# Finding location in android using Gabe Sechan's tutorial

Tags: java, android

I have tried using androidhive's standard tutorial for finding location,but it fails at certain times.So i found another tutorial on this link:

http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/

He uses two classes which implement an interface:

The first class:

```
package com.example.marinamapseg;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;

public class FallbackLocationTracker  implements LocationTracker, LocationTracker.LocationUpdateListener {


    private boolean isRunning;

    private ProviderLocationTracker gps;
    private ProviderLocationTracker net;

    private LocationUpdateListener listener;

    Location lastLoc;
    long lastTime;

    public FallbackLocationTracker(Context context) {
        gps = new ProviderLocationTracker(context, ProviderLocationTracker.ProviderType.GPS);
        net = new ProviderLocationTracker(context, ProviderLocationTracker.ProviderType.NETWORK);
    }

    public void start(){
        if(isRunning){
            //Already running, do nothing
            return;
        }

        //Start both
        gps.start(this);
        net.start(this);
        isRunning = true;
    }

    public void start(LocationUpdateListener update) {
        start();
        listener = update;
    }


    public void stop(){
        if(isRunning){
            gps.stop();
            net.stop();
            isRunning = false;
            listener = null;
        }
    }

    public boolean hasLocation(){
        //If either has a location, use it
        return gps.hasLocation() || net.hasLocation();
    }

    public boolean hasPossiblyStaleLocation(){
        //If either has a location, use it
        return gps.hasPossiblyStaleLocation() || net.hasPossiblyStaleLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation(){
        Location ret = gps.getLocation();
        if(ret == null){
            ret = net.getLocation();
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public Location getPossiblyStaleLocation(){
        Location ret = gps.getPossiblyStaleLocation();
        if(ret == null){
            ret = net.getPossiblyStaleLocation();
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public void onUpdate(Location oldLoc, long oldTime, Location newLoc, long newTime) {
        boolean update = false;

        //We should update only if there is no last location, the provider is the same, or the provider is more accurate, or the old location is stale
        if(lastLoc == null){
            update = true;
        }
        else if(lastLoc != null && lastLoc.getProvider().equals(newLoc.getProvider())){
            update = true;
        }
        else if(newLoc.getProvider().equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            update = true;
        }
        else if (newTime - lastTime > 5 * 60 * 1000){
            update = true;
        }

        if(update){
            lastLoc = newLoc;
            lastTime = newTime;
            if(listener != null){
                listener.onUpdate(lastLoc, lastTime, newLoc, newTime);                  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The second class:

```
package com.example.marinamapseg;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ProviderLocationTracker implements LocationListener, LocationTracker {

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_UPDATE_DISTANCE =  0; 

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_UPDATE_TIME = 0; 

    private LocationManager lm;

    public enum ProviderType{
        NETWORK,
        GPS
    };    
    private String provider;

    private Location lastLocation;
    private long lastTime;

    private boolean isRunning;

    private LocationUpdateListener listener;

    public ProviderLocationTracker(Context context, ProviderType type) {
        lm = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if(type == ProviderType.NETWORK){
            provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
        }
        else{
            provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        }
    }

    public void start(){
        if(isRunning){
            //Already running, do nothing
            return;
        }

        //The provider is on, so start getting updates.  Update current location
        isRunning = true;
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, MIN_UPDATE_TIME, MIN_UPDATE_DISTANCE, this);
        lastLocation = null;
        lastTime = 0;
        return;
    }

    public void start(LocationUpdateListener update) {
        start();
        listener = update;

    }


    public void stop(){
        if(isRunning){
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            isRunning = false;
            listener = null;
        }
    }

    public boolean hasLocation(){
        if(lastLocation == null){
            return false;
        }
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime > 5 * MIN_UPDATE_TIME){
            return false; //stale
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean hasPossiblyStaleLocation(){
        if(lastLocation != null){
            return true;
        }
        return lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider)!= null;
    }

    public Location getLocation(){
        if(lastLocation == null){
            return null;
        }
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime > 5 * MIN_UPDATE_TIME){
            return null; //stale
        }
        return lastLocation;
    }

    public Location getPossiblyStaleLocation(){
        if(lastLocation != null){
            return lastLocation;
        }
        return lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location newLoc) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(listener != null){
            listener.onUpdate(lastLocation, lastTime, newLoc, now);
        }
        lastLocation = newLoc;
        lastTime = now;
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    }
}
```

But the issue is that he has not mentioned as how to use the following two classes in the android app.So i tried the following:

```
FallbackLocationTracker fobj;

fobj=new FallbackLocationTracker(MainActivity.this);
    fobj.start();
    if(fobj.hasLocation())
    {
        Location locobj=fobj.getLocation();
        current_latitude=locobj.getLatitude();
        current_longitude=locobj.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),current_latitude+" "+current_longitude,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        placemarkersonmap();
    }
```

When i debug the code the `hasLocation` method returns false, Because the `onLocationChanged` method in the first class is getting called only after the `haslocation` method is called.So the `lastlocation` object will be null and false would be returned.

But why doesnt `onlocationchanged` get called as soon as the following line runs:

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, MIN_UPDATE_TIME, MIN_UPDATE_DISTANCE, this);
```

Or is there any way somenone can tell me as how to use the code.Please help!!

Answer (score 2):

onLocationChanged is a callback, meaning that it is event driven and does not run until the device detects a change of location. If you are taking location only from GPS, then it can take several minutes before you get a fix. If you are indoors without a clear view of the sky, then it may never run.

Answer (score 1):

You may add the following in your actitvity's onCreate method:

```js
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textViewHeading = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.text_heading);
    textViewLong = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.text_long);
    textViewLat = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.text_lat);
    textViewHeight = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.text_height);
    textViewAccuracy = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.text_accuracy);
    
    counter = (long) 0;
    
    gps = new ProviderLocationTracker(this, 
        ProviderLocationTracker.ProviderType.GPS);
    listener = new LocationUpdateListener() {

      @Override
      public void onUpdate(Location oldLoc, long oldTime, Location newLoc,
          long newTime) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       
       counter = counter + (long) 1;
       if (gps.hasLocation()) {
         text1="GPS has location ( " + counter.toString() + " )";
       } else {
         text1="GPS has no location ( " + counter.toString() + " )";
       }
       
       if (gps.hasPossiblyStaleLocation()) {
         text1 = text1 + " plus stale location";
       }
       
       Double longitude = newLoc.getLongitude();
       Double latitude = newLoc.getLatitude();
       Double height = newLoc.getAltitude();
       Float accuracy = newLoc.getAccuracy();
              
       text2 = "Longitude = " + longitude.toString();
       text3 = "Latitude  = " + latitude.toString();
       text4 = "Altitude  = " + height.toString();
       text5 = "Accuracy  = " + accuracy.toString();
              
       textViewHeading.setText(text1);
       textViewLong.setText(text2);
       textViewLat.setText(text3);
       textViewHeight.setText(text4);
       textViewAccuracy.setText(text5);
      }
      
    };
    gps.start(listener);
    
  } // end method onCreate
```

Comment: It'd be nice to know how to use the fallback location tracker.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this post already has an answer that shows how to use the `ProviderLocationTracker`. I am putting in my answer just to show how easy it get's with the `FallbackLocationTracker`.

I do not remember making any significant changes to the `FallbackLocationTracker` so I am not going to post the whole code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FallbackLocationTracker tracker;
    private Location location;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tracker = new FallbackLocationTracker(MainActivity.this);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Check for permission to access location and start location
        // tracking if permissions are granted and location services 
        // are enabled
        if (locationPermissionGranted && locationServicesEnabled) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        } else {
            // Handle accordingly
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }

    private void startLocationUpdates() {
        tracker.start(new LocationTracker.LocationUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onUpdate(Location oldLocation, long oldTime, 
                         Location newLocation, long newTime) {
                // You will receive updated changes to your location here
                location = newLocation;
            }
        });        
    }

    private void stopLocationUpdates() {
        tracker.stop();
    }
}
```

That's it.

Comment: I was about to write an answer but thankfully you've done it! ;)